# Can install4j 4.x be used to bundle JDK7-based applications?

Tags: java, install4j, unsupported-class-version

I presently have install4j 4.2.3 installed, and we're trying to upgrade our project to JDK 7.  Our package builds are failing with errors about UnsupportedClassVersionException, e.g.:

```
[install4j] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/ourcompany/product/installer/action/FindRelatedInstallationsAction : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[install4j]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[install4j]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
[install4j]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
[install4j]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
[install4j]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
[install4j]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
[install4j]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[install4j]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
[install4j]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
[install4j]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
[install4j]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[install4j]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
[install4j]     at com.sun.beans.finder.ClassFinder.findClass(ClassFinder.java:102)
[install4j]     at com.sun.beans.finder.ClassFinder.resolveClass(ClassFinder.java:169)
[install4j]     at com.sun.beans.ObjectHandler.classForName2(ObjectHandler.java:214)
[install4j]     at com.sun.beans.ObjectHandler.startElement(ObjectHandler.java:248)
[install4j]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:459)
[install4j]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
[install4j]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1327)
[install4j]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2739)
[install4j]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:625)
[install4j]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
[install4j]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:828)
[install4j]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:757)
[install4j]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:133)
[install4j]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1211)
[install4j]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:551)
[install4j]     at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:361)
[install4j]     at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:139)
[install4j]     at java.beans.XMLDecoder$1.run(XMLDecoder.java:265)
[install4j]     at java.beans.XMLDecoder$1.run(XMLDecoder.java:259)
[install4j]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[install4j]     at java.beans.XMLDecoder.getHandler(XMLDecoder.java:259)
[install4j]     at java.beans.XMLDecoder.readObject(XMLDecoder.java:223)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.A.A.L.å(ejt:772)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.F.F.Y(ejt:3262)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.F.F._(ejt:2484)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.F.F.b(ejt:742)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.F.F.o(ejt:3446)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.F.F.G(ejt:2571)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.F.F.J(ejt:1755)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.F.F.I(ejt:1966)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.F.F.l(ejt:93)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.F.F.M(ejt:640)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.C.H.A(ejt:2000)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.A.p(ejt:2111)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.A.A(ejt:712)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.B.È(ejt:1736)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.B.Æ(ejt:3290)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.B.I(ejt:659)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.Install4JApplication.ř(ejt:3031)
[install4j]     at com.A.L.Ň(ejt:2517)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.Install4JApplication.main(ejt:3481)
[install4j]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[install4j]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[install4j]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[install4j]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
[install4j]     at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.runtime.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
```

I also tried with the latest available 4.x (which appears to be 4.2.8) and received the same errors.

I'm not sure if it's related, but our project file was updated to specify a minimum java version of 1.7:

```
<application 
    name="${compiler:PRODUCTNAME} Server" 
    distributionSourceDir="" 
    applicationId="xxxx" 
    mediaDir="../../results" mediaFilePattern="${compiler:sys.shortName}_${compiler:sys.version}_${compiler:sys.platform}" 
    compression="6" 
    lzmaCompression="false" 
    pack200Compression="false" 
    excludeSignedFromPacking="true" 
    keepModificationTimes="false" 
    missingFilesStrategy="warn" 
    shortName="product_server" 
    publisher="${compiler:COMPANYNAME}" 
    publisherWeb="http://ourcompany.com" 
    version="0.0.0" 
    allPathsRelative="true" 
    backupOnSave="false" 
    autoSave="false" 
    convertDotsToUnderscores="true" 
    macSignature="????" 
    installerName="" 
    javaMinVersion="1.7" 
    javaMaxVersion="" 
    allowBetaVM="false" 
    jdkMode="runtimeJre" 
    jdkName="">
```

I've tested things with install4j 5.x and the build does run, but I thought I'd check to see if there was something simple I'm missing that'd let us stay with 4.x.  Google doesn't seem to find much when I searched on relevant terms, unfortunately. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: While I don't know the product, the error implies it isn't using 1.7 when it is doing that step. Does this answer mean anything to you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18129625

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed that option; sadly after configuring jdk 7u60 specifically I get the same errors.  I also checked my default java's -version, JAVA_HOME, etc. and all are pointing at the sake JDK.

Comment: er, *same* jdk.  Though a bit of sake might make this troubleshooting experience much nicer, I must admit.

Answer (score 0):

When using install4j 4.x, you have to compile your custom code with `-target 1.6.`. That's because the install4j compiler is running with Java 6.